# Как исправить ошибку при создании нового Django проекта

Tags: python-3.x, django, cmd, django-admin, pip

Пытаюсь создать новый проект, но когда я прописываю строку django-admin startproject newsite, то вылезает вот такая ошибка.

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

Далее, на ютубе я нашел такое решение:
Прописать в командной строке ***python -m pip install --upgrade pip***

Но мне пишет это:

```
C:\Users\Владелец>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\владелец\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (19.3.1)
```

Что делать?

Comment: Только одна строчка с текстом ошибки была? Мб есть еще и полотно текста -- трасса стека?

Comment: @gil9red эту ошибку выдает постоянно. Даже когда я пытался сам django скачать. Но потом я просто скачал его в pycharm

Comment: @S1riyS если пути у Вас прописаны корректно, то попробуйте более глобальное решение `python  -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip` или `python3  -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip` соответственно.

Comment: @gil9red попробовал оба варианта, но все равно при попытке создания проекта вылазит та же самая ошибка. Может быть все таки пути прописаны не корректно (если так, то как это исправить)?\

Answer (score 0):

Короче говоря, проще всего было применить самый банальный способ - это просто удалить все к чертям. В моем случаи это было: **PyCharm**, **Python 3.7** и **Python Launcher (на всякий случай)**. Все свои программы и библиотеки я переместил из соответствующих папок на рабочий стол. Далее я все переустановил и вернул на свои места. *Если вы тоже используйте PyCharm, то не забудьте указать в настройках свою версию питона*.

Теперь все работает, можете попробовать.

Comment: Я бы ещё избавился от кириллицы в путях.